# WebAPI accepts broken JSON send via Fiddler

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

For some reason I can send these two JSON requests to my WebAPI and it'll accept and create an User. One with double quotes and one without.

```
{"Username":"Bob", "FirstName":"Foo", "LastName":"Bar", "Password":"123", "Headline":"Tuna"}

{Username:"Bob", FirstName:"Foo", LastName:"Bar", Password:"123", Headline:"Tuna"}
```

This is the method which creates an User.

```
    // localhost:12345/api/controller/create
    [ActionName("create")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = user.UserId }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
```

However I'm able to make a successful POST request without the `/create` at the end of URL. I'm assuming that the reason for the success POST request is because whether or not the action name is present it will search for a `Post` in the method name.

So my question is, what's the purpose of the action name then? How can I make it so it's a must in the URL? Also why is it accepting both JSON requests and how can I make it accept one or the other.

**EDIT:**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

// Routing by Action-name
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{username}",
            defaults: new { username = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Thank you for your time

/twice

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it so it's a must in the URL?

By changing your route definition in `~/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` and making the action name explicitly appear in your route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

> Also why is it accepting both JSON requests and how can I make it accept one or the other.

Because the Web API uses JSON.NET as JSON serializer which accepts both of them.

Comment: I have two config routes, I've updated my post with them. Why won't this work? The second config, has an action in the route and it's only the `username` that is optional.

Comment: because the first route still matches

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `App_Start` for the route that's registered for your API calls you'll see:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

You'll notice that no `action` is specified. If you want to map to action names, you can change it to:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

But then you'll always be required to set an action (unless it's a `GET` which is the default).  You can no longer `POST` directly toe controller, you'll always need to add an `action`.

Per [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) the default behavior is to look for a method that starts with the HTTP method used:

> To find the action, Web API looks at the HTTP method, and then looks
>   for an action whose name begins with that HTTP method name. For
>   example, with a GET request, Web API looks for an action that starts
>   with "Get...", such as "GetContact" or "GetAllContacts".  This
>   convention applies only to GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods. You can
>   enable other HTTP methods by using attributes on your controller.
>   We’ll see an example of that later.

Another option is to create different controllers for your different `GET` calls, which is what I've done in the past.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this does `action = "get"`? Also I updated my question, I included my webconfigs but it's still not working. I can still do POST without `/create`.

Comment: `action = "get"` is saying the default `{action}` parameter is `"get"`. It's trying to replicate the original behavior of Web API. Also, if you're using both routes, posting without an action will still follow the first route. You'd need to remove it.

Comment: But if I remove the first config then how will I be able to GET users by ID? I want to be able to GET users by id and username which currently works. However I see your point in it allowing me to POST without `/create` as it then follows the first route config. Any idea how I would set it up without removing the first config or disabling me from getting users by id also?

Comment: The example would allow you to `GET` by ID as a default. Anything other than `GET` you would need to specify the action, like `POST` or `DELETE`. That is what the `action = "get"` does.